# Flutter - Local_auth (NotAvailable, Security credentials not available., null, null)

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, fingerprint, localauthentication

my flutter version 3.7.12 / Dart Version 2.19.6

any one know some solution?

Thanks

here  is my error

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(NotAvailable, Security credentials not available., null, null)
E/flutter ( 5073): #0      LocalAuthAndroid.authenticate
package:local_auth_android/local_auth_android.dart:69
E/flutter ( 5073): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5073): #1      _InnAppLoginState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:capp_new/…/auth_innapp/innapp_login.dart:345
E/flutter ( 5073): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: this happen when a package which deals with native code is added to the project.  just close your app and rebuild it again.